# ArrayStoreException when i try to use template in java array

Tags: java, arrays

Deque interface

```
interface Deque<Item> {
    int size();

    void addFirst(Item item);

    void addLast(Item item);

    Item removeFirst();

    Item removeLast();

    Item get(int index);

    boolean isEmpty();

    void printDeque();

}
```

This is my customized ArrayDeque, and i need to store "Character" type but got ArrayStoreException.

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class Array2Deque<T> implements Deque<T> {
    private T[] items = (T[]) new Objects[8];

    @Override
    public void addLast(T item) {
        items[0] = item;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void addFirst(T t) {

    }

    @Override
    public T removeFirst() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public T removeLast() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void printDeque() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deque<Character> dq = new Array2Deque<>();
        Character ch = 'h';
        dq.addLast(ch);
    }
}
```

error info:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Character
    at Array2Deque.addLast(Array2Deque)
    at Array2Deque.main(Array2Deque)
```

ArrayStoreException means I try to store the wrong type data. But I am sure that I create a T type array and set T to "Character", why cannot i store the "Character" type data.

Comment: Hey! Is this the full and the right code?

Comment: Can you please post the entire code? The given portion won't even compile.

Comment: Sorry, I omit the interface, and now that's the whole stuff.

Answer (score 3):

```java
(T[]) new Objects[8];
```

You are creating an array of [`Objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html) that is a utility class, which provides static utility functions. What you probably want is an array of [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html).

```java
(T[]) new Object[8];
```

The error occurs because `Character` is not a subtype of `Objects`. It does work with `Object` because `Character` is a subtype of it.